# React Virtualized: sticky content in a Collection

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-virtualized

Is it possible to let the content of a cell in a react-virtualized Collection stick to a side when scrolling? I normally do this by using position sticky but this does not work for the content in a Collection.

I'm building a Grid TV Guide like the one in the image below. When scrolling the content of the most left visible cell of a row should stick to the left side of the screen.

[image: tv_grid]

I am able to get this working without using react-virtualized, but after scrolling through the guide for a while too much data is rendered and the page becomes very slow.

Can any of you help me? I would be very grateful.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to make an extra element that looks like the column that is to be sticky, and positioning it over it, e.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/l5z0wvpj77